# How can i enable GPU in those lines?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

how can I speed up the calculations for this equation using GPU or cuda as the file contains 30.000 points

```
points = pd.read_csv('file.dat', sep='\t', usecols=[0, 1])
d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((max_id, max_id))) 
dis = sch.distance.pdist(points, 'euclidean') 
n = 0
for i in range(max_id):
    print(i)
    for j in range(i + 1, max_id):
        d.at[i, j] = dis[n]
        d.at[j, i] = d.at[i, j]
        n += 1
```

EDIT

i tried

```
    points = genfromtxt(path, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0, 1])
    points =torch.tensor(points)
    d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((max_id, max_id))) 
    dis = torch.cdist(points)
```

but got

```
TypeError: cdist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x2'
```

does that mean I need to read points or the two columns of points separately?

Answer (score 2):

NumPy doesn't natively support GPUs. Though you can use some libraries which are friendly with `numpy` and supports GPU. One of the option like that would be to use `PyTorch`. [`torch.cdist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html) would be one of the function you can look at (Then you don't need to organize it like that using for loops). Also there is [`torch.nn.functional.pdist`](https://torch.nn.functional.pdist). Note also that, you don't need to use for loop in second case. Once you get the output, you can just `reshape` it as per your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i'm trying it now but got `TypeError: cdist(): argument 'x1' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @sammo `x1 = torch.tensor(x1)`

Comment: Thanks can you please see the edit post

Comment: @sammo  Also don't edit the question once answered. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @sammo.: It should be something like `torch.cdist(points, points)` in your case.

Comment: yes that's right but still have a problem

Comment: @sammo Ask a new question and tag me here. I can take a look at it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72122133/only-one-element-tensors-can-be-converted

Comment: @sammo If this answer or the other answer helped try to select it so that it helps the future users.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, numpy doesn't support GPU, but it's not impossible to speed up your program. It seems that you want to write the calculated distance value to the non diagonal position. I use the pure numpy array to show you how to speed up your program:

```
>>> max_id = 5
>>> d = np.zeros((max_id, max_id))
>>> dis = np.arange(max_id // 2 * (max_id - 1)) ** 2    # set the value at will
>>> d[np.triu_indices(max_id, k=1)] = dis
>>> d + d.T    # d += d.T is better
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  4.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0., 16., 25., 36.],
       [ 1., 16.,  0., 49., 64.],
       [ 4., 25., 49.,  0., 81.],
       [ 9., 36., 64., 81.,  0.]])
```

After testing, when the `max_id` is 500, the accelerated program is more than ten times faster than the previous one:

```
>>> def loop(max_id):
...     d = np.zeros((max_id, max_id))
...     dis = np.arange(max_id // 2 * (max_id - 1)) ** 2
...     n = 0
...     for i in range(max_id):
...         for j in range(i + 1, max_id):
...             d[i, j] = d[j, i] = dis[n]
...             n += 1
...
>>> def triu(max_id):
...     d = np.zeros((max_id, max_id))
...     dis = np.arange(max_id // 2 * (max_id - 1)) ** 2
...     d[np.triu_indices(max_id, k=1)] = dis
...     d += d.T
...
>>> timeit(lambda: loop(500), number=10)
0.546407600006205
>>> timeit(lambda: triu(500), number=10)
0.0350386000063736
```

If you want to do more complex loop operations, you can learn about [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/).

**Update:**

It seems that the size of non diagonal block is larger than size of `dis`, you just need to slice the result of `triu_indices`:

```
dis_size = dis.size
i, j = np.triu_indices(max_id, k=1)
d[i[:dis_size], j[:dis_size]] = dis
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried your second function `triu` but got `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (450000000,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (450015000,)` in this line  `d[np.triu_indices(max_id, k=1)] = dis` where i checked the shape of `dis` and was `450000000` but `d` was `450015000`

Comment: @sammo This is because the size of your `points` is inconsistent with the size of non diagonal blocks. You just need to slice the larger array.

Comment: how can i do that please

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort , i tried your solution but got `Killed`