# only one element tensors can be converted

Tags: python, pandas, torch

I was trying to speed up the code for calculating the distance by this code

```
    points = genfromtxt(path, delimiter='\t', usecols=[0, 1])
    max_id = len(points)
    points =torch.tensor(points)
    d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((max_id, max_id)))  
    dis = torch.cdist(points,points) 
    n = 0
    for i in range(max_id):
        print(i)
        for j in range(i + 1, max_id):
            d.at[i, j] = dis[n]
            d.at[j, i] = d.at[i, j]
            n += 1
```

i got

```
d.at[i, j] = dis[n]
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: You are trying to convert a multi-element tensor to a scalar, which doesn't make sense. You can convert a list of numbers to a number.  I am guessing `dis[n]` is not a scalar, it's a list of numbers. Try printing `dis[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
points = torch.randint(1,5,(4,2)).float() # You already have this 
print(points)
dis = torch.cdist(points,points)
print(dis)
```

##### Output

```
tensor([[2., 1.],
        [1., 2.],
        [3., 4.],
        [4., 4.]])
tensor([[0.0000, 1.4142, 3.1623, 3.6056],
        [1.4142, 0.0000, 2.8284, 3.6056],
        [3.1623, 2.8284, 0.0000, 1.0000],
        [3.6056, 3.6056, 1.0000, 0.0000]])
```

Here is a snippet to help you understand how to work with `cdist`. It is returning the scalar distance already. You don't need to do anything extra. You already have the `dis` matrix here.

You want the `dis` tensor to be in `numpy` array you can simply call `numpy()` function.

```
dis_np = dis.numpy()
```

Comment: i tried it but got `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` at this line `d.at[i, j] = dis_np[n]`

Comment: @sammo Maybe share the text file using github or some way...otherwise its difficult to tell. But my answer should have been sufficient to get to the solution.